# My .exe python program doesn't launch, why?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

exe file using pyinstaller, but this .exe file displays the cmd window on the millisecond and disappears.

here is a code

```
import os
print ("xd")
os.system("Pause")
```

Comment: Try leaving the program to wait for input at the end of execution with `input()`. This way terminal should remain open.

Comment: i don't see terminal, when i was click .exe file

Comment: can u explain further.
Can u go in you'r exe path in cmd and run this code?
replace the whosh by your exe name
```
whosh.exe
```
Run this command in terminal Then you should get the error from the python executable.

Comment: Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Nowy folder\build\xd\python39.dll'.
LoadLibrary: the specified module could not be found

 .

Comment: Then you're Python is broken

Comment: Try to reinstall it

Comment: i was reinstall python but did not work